# AsyncTask() with HTTP log in not working

Tags: android, mysql, android-intent, android-asynctask

The main aim is for me to connect my app with mysql database on the web. Data is collected in JSON format.. and from the log cat the data seem to be coming in but my app keeps on crashing after receiving the data..
This is the error i got from the logCat

```
    E/SpannableStringBuilder(3081): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-08 06:17:57.720: E/SpannableStringBuilder(3081): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-08 06:17:57.740: E/SpannableStringBuilder(3081): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-08 06:17:57.740: E/SpannableStringBuilder(3081): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-08 06:18:05.655: E/JSON(3081): {"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"20","user":{"name":"mash","email":"mafulun4real@gmail.com","created_at":"28\/04\/13 06:27:"}}n
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at com.nairation.rss.LoginActivity.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:70)
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at com.nairation.rss.LoginActivity.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:1)
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
09-08 06:18:05.665: E/AndroidRuntime(3081):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is the code

```
package com.nairation.rss;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.nairation.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.nairation.library.JSONParser;
import com.nairation.library.UserFunctions;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LoginActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>{

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private int responsecode = 0;
    private JSONParser jparser;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Login activity;

    public LoginActivity(ProgressDialog progressDialog){
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int count = params.length;
        if(count == 2){
            username = params[0];
            password = params[1];
            UserFunctions userfunc = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject jp = userfunc.loginUser(username, password);
            try{
                if(jp.getString("success") != null){
                    String res = jp.getString("success");

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        //Dat means the use is successfully logged in
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(activity.getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject juser = jp.getJSONObject("user");
                        userfunc.logoutUser(activity.getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(juser.getString("name"), juser.getString("email"), jp.getString("uid"), juser.getString("created_at"));
                        responsecode = 1;
                    }
                }
            } catch(NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            responsecode = 0;
        }
        return responsecode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer responsecode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onPostExecute(responsecode);
        EditText username = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.loginname);
        EditText pword = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.loginpass);

        if (responsecode == 1){
            username.setText("");
            pword.setText("");
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (responsecode == 0){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            activity.showLoginError(responsecode);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: PAste your activity file code

Comment: You must be using spannable string to which you are passing a zero length value...please check

Comment: @NightCrawler i don't even know where that error is coming from i just checked the whole of my xml and there is no place i gave any textview span

Comment: what is the "n" at the end of this line:{"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"20","user":{"name":"mash","email":"mafulun4real@gmail.com","created_at":"28\/04\/13 06:27:"}}n

Comment: wanted to append \n to implement a new line but i din't think that could be the reason..is it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, instead of initialising your `AsyncTask` with `ProgressDialog` isn't wrong, but in my opinion you should pass an `Activity` context there. In that way you can use it's `Context` to create your `ProgressDialog` and to get properly your views initialised too. So it should look something like this :

```
private Context mContext;

public LoginActivity(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer responsecode) {
    //super.onPostExecute(responsecode);
    EditText username = (EditText) ((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.loginname);
    EditText pword = (EditText) ((Activity)mContext).findViewById(R.id.loginpass);

    // and etc ...
}
```

And something else, which I consider as better use of `AsyncTask`: if you are manipulating some views in your `onPostExecute` and you are doing that in only one `Activity`, you should create your `LoginActivity` as inner class of your `Login` Activity. In this way, declaring your `EditText`'s as global variable for your `Activity` you can use them without any problem in `onPostExecute`. If you are going to use this `AsyncTask` in more than one place in your whole application, the better option for me is to create an interface for example:

```
public interface OnLoginRequestHandler(){
    public void onLoginHandler(int responseCode);
}
```

and in your `onPostExecute` just fire `mMyLoginHandler.onLoginHandler(mMyResponseCode);`. You should know that you have to implement `OnLoginRequestHandler` from your `Activity` and `@Override` `onLoginHandler` so you can get the result and update properly your UI depending on that.

Hope this helps you to understand which suits the best for your purposes. : )

Comment: Thanks man...just like magic the app is working...now i can go to bed...thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Where is the variable activity of the type `Login` being initialized?. If responseCode is 0 then onPostExecute runs, you get in the if statement and activity has not been initialized, hence it is null.

Comment: it is the class where the LoginActivity which is extending the asynctask is been initialised from..

Comment: I do not understand. You declare the variable "activity" but it never gets initialized. I think that is what is causing your NPE.